# Printing string in Perl

Tags: string, perl, escaping, character

Is there an easy way, using a subroutine maybe, to print a string in Perl without escaping every special character?

This is what I want to do:

```
print   DELIMITER <I don't care what is here> DELIMITER
```

So obviously it will great if I can put a string as a delimiter instead of special characters.

Comment: Can you give some examples of some strings that you find troublesome to print?

Comment: There are lot of single quotes in it.Idea is to print the contents of string irrespective of what is inside of it. A subroutine to print where you can specify the string delimiter.

Comment: @alertjean That would be the `q//` and `qq//` generic string operators.  You can specify the delimiter, so you can say `my $s = qq(this contains " and ');`  There are two types of delimiters: bracketing and non-bracketing.  The bracketing delimiters are `()`, `[]`, `{}`, and `<>`.  The first character starts the string and the second closes it, with the caveat that nesting is allowed (so `qq(He said "Hey (that was my paren)");` is a valid string).  Non-bracketing delimiters close the string when seen a second time (e.g. `qq/foo/;`).

Comment: This question still does not make sense.  Please show the code that is broken.

Comment: Can I use a string as a delimiter ? Say qq DELIMITER foo DELIMITER

Comment: To use a string you really need to use the heredoc style, I see some listed below, but wanted to be sure to draw your attention to them.

Answer (score 8):

[perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators), under "Quote and Quote-like Operators", contains everything you need.

> While we usually think of quotes as literal values, in Perl they function as operators, providing various kinds of interpolating and pattern matching
>   capabilities.  Perl provides customary quote characters for these behaviors, but also provides a way for you to choose your quote character for any of
>   them.  In the following table, a "{}" represents any pair of delimiters you choose.
>
> ```
> Customary  Generic        Meaning        Interpolates
>     ''       q{}          Literal             no
>     ""      qq{}          Literal             yes
>     ``      qx{}          Command             yes*
>             qw{}         Word list            no
>     //       m{}       Pattern match          yes*
>             qr{}          Pattern             yes*
>              s{}{}      Substitution          yes*
>             tr{}{}    Transliteration         no (but see below)
>     <<EOF                 here-doc            yes*
>
>     * unless the delimiter is ''.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = q(this is a "string");
print $str;
```

if you mean quotes and apostrophes with 'special characters'

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `__DATA__` directive which will treat all of the following lines as a file that can be accessed from the `DATA` handle:

```
while (<DATA>) {
   print # or do something else with the lines
}

__DATA__
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Some::Module;
....
```

or you can use a heredoc:

```
my $string = <<'END';  #single quotes prevent any interpolation
#!/usr/bin/perl -b
use Some::Module;
....
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The printing is not doing special things to the escapes, double quoted strings are doing it.  You may want to try single quoted strings:

```
print 'this is \n', "\n";
```

In a single quoted string the only characters that must be escaped are single quotes and a backslash that occurs immediately before the end of the string (i.e. `'foo\\'`).

It is important to note that interpolation does not work with single quoted strings, so

```
print 'foo is $foo', "\n";
```

Will not print the contents of `$foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much use any character you want with `q` or `qq`. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict; use warnings;

print q∞This is a test∞;
print qq☼\nThis is another test\n☼;
print q»But, what is the point?»;
print qq\nYou are just making life hard on yourself!\n;
print qq¿That last one is tricky\n¿;
```

You cannot use `qq DELIMITER foo DELIMITER`. However, you could use heredocs for a similar effect:

```
print <<DELIMITER
...
DELIMETER
;
```

or

```
print <<'DELIMETER'
...
DELIMETER
;
```

but your source code would be *really* ugly.

Comment: I have a guaranteed solution: code points U+FFFE and F+FFFF (amongst others) are guaranteed to be illegal for interchange, but you may use them internally. This also includes code points > 0x10_FFFF, like `\x{DEADBEEF}`.

Comment: I thought you were supposed to put the semicolon on the line with the << to allow for multiple heredocs in the same line? i.e. `print <<'DELIMITER'; ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a string literally and you have Perl 5.10 or later then

```
say 'This is a string with "quotes"' ;
```

will print the string with a newline.. The importaning thing is to use single quotes `' '` rather than double ones `" "`

Comment: you may use `say` to do this but you need to `use feature 'say'` or specify a minimum version as in `use 5.10.0` to do this, or you can in a one liner with -E rather than -e. See `perldoc feature`.