# Trouble with printing <bbb>-constructs in perl

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I have a small CGI perl script that I would like to print a file containing plain text to be output as html. So far, so god, however, the file contains some text enclosed with < and >, ie.  `<bbb>`. The problem is that the `<bbb>` are removed. The same happens when I do a simple print statement like this:

```
print "aaa <bbb> ccc";
```

displays

```
aaa  ccc
```

I have searched around, but not been able to find the solution. Amongst others, I have found this [Printing string in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108678/printing-string-in-perl), but can't really see how the answer applies?

Comment: I have no trouble with `print "aaa <bbb> ccc";` it displays: `aaa <bbb> ccc`.
Try to change double quotes to single quote, maybe it can escape the ignoring delimiter.

Comment: Are you trying the example print statement you provided by running your script from the command line, or is it a CGI script and you're viewing it's output in the browser?  In the latter case you'll need to change `<` to `&lt;` or the browser will intepret `<bbb>` as HTML. The `escapeHTML()` function will do that conversion for you.

Comment: If I create a file named `a.pl` with that line of `print` and run `perl a.pl` in iTerm / Terminal. That produce the string exactly. So I think the environment that runs it is something different. Could you supply more info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you displaying the output in a web browser? Then try

```
print "aaa &lt;bbb&gt; ccc";
```

and see the [`HTML::Entities`](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities) module if you'll need to make conversions like this on other lines of text.

Comment: Thanks, yes. It is plain text to be displayed with pre-tags. I will then substitute the <'s an >'s with the corresponding html-characters...

Comment: In my case, just substituting those two characters are sufficient. However, I do see that the built-in escapeHTML-function in CGI would be better in the general case, as @grant suggests.