# "qx!" vs. "qx/" in Perl

Tags: perl

Is there a functional difference between `qx!command!` and `qx/command/` (where `command` represents some sort of Bash function)?

I'm having a hard time locating this in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: Read the "Gory details of parsing quoted constructs" section.

Comment: Read the ["Gory details of parsing quoted constructs"](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs) section and the ["Quote-Like Operators"](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators) section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the characters you can use without escaping them within the command.

```
qx!/!
qx/\//;
```

Comment: On the other hand, `qx'...'` does have a functional difference: It acts as a single-quoted string literal instead of a double-quoted string literal.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks.  Do you know where the Perl documentation talks about which delimiters are valid vs. invalid?  Like, I'm assuming that `w` is not a valid delimiter. :P

Comment: @alex See also
[Quote-Like-Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) and [Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs)

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms Thanks Chris, in which section of either links you provided do they define the set of "non-bracketing delimiters" vs. "bracketing delimiters"?

Comment: @alex From the "gory details" section: `For the constructs except here-docs, single characters are used as starting and ending delimiters. If the starting delimiter is an opening punctuation (that is (, [, {, or < ), the ending delimiter is the corresponding closing punctuation (that is ), ], }, or >). If the starting delimiter is an unpaired character like / or a closing punctuation, the ending delimiter is the same as the starting delimiter. Therefore a / terminates a qq// construct, while a ] terminates both qq[] and qq]] constructs.`

Comment: @alex see also Chas. Owen's comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108678/printing-string-in-perl#comment4424387_4108678